# How to generate dbgsym deb pkg for TSDuck

Tags: dpkg

I'm building the [TSDuck project that is on GitHub](https://github.com/tsduck/tsduck).

To generate comprehensive debugging symbols in the binaries, I use gcc's -g flag:

```
export ADDITIONAL_CXX_FLAGS='-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -march=x86-64-v3 -flto -g'
make CXXFLAGS_EXTRA="${ADDITIONAL_CXX_FLAGS}" NOTEST=1 NOSTATIC=1 NOGITHUB=1 NODEKTEC=1 NOCURL=1 NOPCSC=1 NOEDITLINE=1 NOSRT=1 NOHIDES=1 NOEDITLINE=1 NORIST=1 NOVATEK=1 installer
```

The resultant command generates something like tsduck.deb and a tsduck-dev.deb (but also includes the version and architecture in the filenames).

The problem is that the resultant binaries are significantly larger in comparison with debuginfo (~7MiB vs ~80MiB). Is there any way to strip the binaries similarly to how some package managers will provide a -dbgsym.deb ? For the record, I'm not well-versed in the construction of Debian-like packages

There is a tsduck.control file where I tried to add an additional package:

```
Package: tsduck
Source: tsduck
Version: {{VERSION}}
Maintainer: Thierry Lelegard <thierry@lelegard.fr>
Architecture: {{ARCH}}
Section: free/video
Priority: optional
Depends: libc6,
 libsrt,
 librist,
 libedit,
 libusb,
 libpcsc,
 libcurl,
 libstdc++6
Conflicts: tsduck-dev (<= 2.28.2441)
Description: MPEG Transport Stream Toolkit
 TSDuck, the MPEG Transport Stream Toolkit, provides some simple utilities to
 process MPEG Transport Streams (TS), either as recorded files or live streams.

Package: tsduck-dbgsym
Version: {{VERSION}}
Maintainer: Thierry Lelegard <thierry@lelegard.fr>
Architecture: any
Section: debug
Priority: extra
Depends:
    tsduck (= {{VERSION}})
Description: Debugging symbols for TSDuck
 TSDuck, the MPEG Transport Stream Toolkit, provides some simple utilities to
 process MPEG Transport Streams (TS), either as recorded files or live streams.
 This package contains the debugging symbols for TSDuck.
```

with an accompanying rules file:

```
override_dh_strip:
        dh_strip --dbg-package=tsduck-dbgsym
```

but I very quickly started receiving errors:

```
dpkg-deb: error: parsing file '.../code/tsduck_source/pkg/installers/tmp/DEBIAN/control' near line 17 package 'tsduck-dbgsym':
 several package info entries found, only one allowed
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 23.10
- gcc-13